How prevalent are HUDs in civilian aircraft?
Head-up displays (HUDs) seem to be a must in modern war aircraft, and have been for quite a while.  This is not much of a surprise for an aircraft flown by a two- or, often enough, one-person crew who has to fly the aircraft, or rather, a flying weapon system, into an unknown mission into a hostile area, not just flying the aircraft in higly dynamic maneuvers, but also operating a wide array of offensive and defensive weaponry.

Now, HUDs are certainly available for all kinds of civilian aircraft as well.  Earlier, we learned that while they are ceratinly availlable for light GA aircraft, their cost keeps the number of installed system on such aircraft down.  For the sector of corporate jets, and certainly for the big airliners, HUDs are often available as a factory option.

What I'd like to know is:  How prevalent are HUDs on civilian aircraft (we heard of light aircraft earlier, so we can exclude them here)? And what is the current trend, have they proven to be effective? Do they increase safety, do they reduce workload on the flight crew?  And if so, will we see more HUDs installed on aircraft in the future?

One element of answer in  Which airlines did use a HUD for their A380?. China requires a quota of HUD by airline (100% in 2025, domestic only), in order to speed up airport operations.

The 2015 question is from an older era. Today, you can get one straight from Garmin, the GHD 2100. It has first flown on the Cessna Longitude in 2017. That's a business jet, but definitely not an airliner, where HUDs are gradually becoming the norm.
This is a projection HUD, like military and commercial ones, and appears to use a proper combiner glass, allowing to to be focused at infinity, removing the need for eye refocusing between the HUD and the terrain.

As to the effectiveness of HUDs in general aviation, the opinions differ. The most authoritative should be the 2009 FSF study, which labeled them a safety improvement. This article discusses the findings in a broader light.
The study's conclusion was that a set of measures, including a HUD, displaying data from angle of attack sensor (or rather three such sensors, as we've painfully learned), TCAS, could have improved the odds in as many as 38% of accidents.
A tougher question is whether a HUD would be useful in a light GA aircraft without all of the sensors considered by the FSF in their study. Some studies have measured a considerable risk of the pilot missing objects during the transition from symbology to normal vision, which increases for dim objects. It follows up on past NASA research that shows HUD-to-world transitions to take additional time and can divide the pilot's attention.
So there is some evidence that HUDs might have detrimental effects for VFR flight, particularly in marginal VFR or night VFR, but it's nowhere as authoritative as the FSF's unambiguous endorsement of HUDs for commercial aviation. Both studies above were more of the conclusion that HUDs should be redesigned in a way that better blends in with the real world, rather than avoided.
The Garmin example with synthetic vision on clearly isn't such a redesign, but the Longitude isn't a VFR airplane either. In fact, Acuario's home-made example might be closer to the minimalist display practical for light GA in VFR.
